# Styling SPAN within a DIV

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have the following:

```
<DIV class="msg-warn">
 <SPAN>some message</SPAN>
</DIV>
```

I would like to add a `background-color` to the `msg-warn` class on the `DIV` as to have the `SPAN` inherit the said background-color.  I can't apply a class to the `SPAN`.

How can I achieve this? (no javascript please, just CSS)

**EDIT**: I found that the `DIV` inherits something that makes it 1px in height...

Comment: do you want the span to have a different background color or that should simply inherit background-color? if thats the case try this: http://jsfiddle.net/zcmhh/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just add it to `.msg-warn` if you want to style the *whole class* and have it inherit.

```
.msg-warn {
    background-color:#F00;
}
```

If you want to style *all* `<span>`s within .msg-warn target like this:

```
.msg-warn span {
    background-color:#F00;
}
```

If you want to style *all direct descendant* `<span>`s (immediate children, not children of children) use `>`

```
.msg-warn > span {
    background-color:#F00;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried something like the following?

```
div.msg-warn > span {
   background-color: #f00;
}
```